# Php mysqli_query returns error but phpmyadmin works

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I know there are other questions like mine here but nothing seems to help me since in my case is a lot of different. Basically I a big algoirthm which computes stuff and puts SQL strings into an array and then I take that array and query it one by one in a for loop. I have done that in the past for more complicated stuff as well. However this time, which is not different than the other times I am trying to execute my query and it returns false. When I print it out so check if my variables are correct and run it through phpmyadmin it works perfectly no problems there. Please if someone is way more experienced can spot what is the error because I spent 1 day and I am hopeless. May be a silly one but like I said there is no different than the other times and I have done the same technique many times(big computation, make sql strings and then execute them oneby one)

```
mysqli_query($conn,$sqls[0]);
echo $sqls[0];
echo "mysqli error: " . mysqli_error($conn) . "<br>";
```

made as simple as possible to check for error. $sqls is basically the array.

and I get this :

```
INSERT INTO driverPaySheets (`driverid`,`missionRef`,`days`,`nights`,`rules`,`dateFrom`,`dateTill`) VALUES('4','ed5d68791186038421ab3b7df98df925','1','0.5','1','1490068800','1490103000')
```

> mysqli error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
>   ' at line 1

which doesnt even help me because it doesnt even give me the error.

Comment: there is no error in this query.

Comment: Well I know this but php mysqli_query thinks otherwise

Comment: Does `$sqls[0]` contain any other content that's not visibly printed when you `echo` it?  HTML tags?  Unprintable characters?

Comment: Try it with ` commas in the values. You got the same error?

Comment: $sqls[0] holds only what it shows above ONLY. I even var_dump the thing

Comment: @subgeo Sorry mate your comment is a bit ambiguous. I am using commas per value

Comment: are you positively sure that this line is causing the error? can you just run a hard-coded query instead of a variable ad add a distinct visible mark to the error message

Comment: You might also put <pre></pre> around both the SQL statement and error message echos. Also view source, the browser may be hiding some special character.

Comment: I am 100% sure because I have commented it out and tried any prior queries. Basically it would not come to this point if the algorithm failed at any pre stage

Comment: Are PHP error messages turned on?

Comment: Unless there's a problem with the PHP code, your output should at least contain the "mysqli error:" text

Comment: You see, it's you who need a solution, not us. Surely you can tell us that you did everything and won't do anything to refine a problem. But, you know, it won't help you to find that silly typo that you are after.

Comment: It does contain mysqli error you can read it above

Comment: Again. I am not your teacher. So don't bother with excuses.

Comment: $sql[0] is the trouble maker i think show us how is declared